# Python - Plot.ly - MySQL Real time streaming visualization

Tags: python, mysql, data-visualization, plotly

Hope you're well and thanks for reading.

Been revisiting an old project, leveraging plotly to stream data out of mysql with python in-between the two. I've never had great luck w/ plot.ly (which I'm sure relates more to my understanding than their platform), streams/iframes seem to stall over time and I am not apt enough to troubleshoot completely.

**My current symptom is this: Plots arbitrarily stall - I'm pushing data, but the iframe isn't updating.**

**The current solution is: Refresh the browser every X minutes.**

The solution works, but it's aggrevating, because I dont understand why the visual is stalling in the first place (is it me, is it them, etc).

As I was reviewing some of the documentation, specifically this link:
https://plot.ly/streaming/

I noticed they call out NOT continually opening and closing streams, and that heartbeats should be placed every so often to keep things alive/fresh.

Here's what I'm currently calling every 10 minutes:

```
pullData(mysql)
format data 

open(plotly.stream1)
write data to plotly.stream1
close(plotly.stream1) 

open(plotly.stream2)
write data to plotly.stream2
close(plotly.stream2)
```

Based on what I am reading, it sounds like I should actually execute the script once on startup, and keep the streams open, but heartbeat() them every 15 or-so seconds between actual write() calls like this:

```
open(plotly.stream1)
open(plotly.stream2)

every 10 minutes:
    pullData(mysql)
    format data

    write data to plotly.stream1
    write data to plotly.stream2

while not pulling and writing:
    every 15 seconds:
        heartbeat(plotly.stream1)
        heartbeat(plotly.stream2)

if error:
    close(plotly.stream1) 
    close(plotly.stream2)
```

Please excuse the sudo-mess, I'm just trying to convey an idea. Anyone have any advice? I started on my original path of opening, writing, closing based on the streaming example, but that's a one time write. The other example is a constant stream of data. I'm somewhere in between those two.

Furthermore - is this train of thought even related to the iframe not refreshing? Part of me believes the symptom is unrelated to my idea - the data is getting to plot.ly fine - it's my session that's expiring, or the iframe "connection" that's going stale. If the symptom is unrelated, at least I'll have made my source code a bit cleaner and more appropriate.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Thanks
-justin

Answer (score 0):

Plotly will close a stream that is inactive for more than 60 seconds. You must send a newline down the streaming channel (a heartbeat) to keep it open. I recommend every 30 seconds.

Your first code example may not work as expected because the client side websocket (that connects the Plot to our system) may close when your first source stream (the stream that connects your script to our system) exits. When you disconnect a source stream a signal is sent to our system that lets it know your stream is now inactive. If a new source stream does not reconnect quickly we close the client connecting websockets.

Now, when your script gets more data and opens a new stream it will successfully stream data to our system but the client-side websocket, now closed, will not pass the data to the Plot. We will cache a certain amount of points for you behind the scenes so that when you refresh the page the websocket reconnects and you get the last n points (where n is set by max-points in the API call).

This is why sending the heartbeat is important. We keep the source stream open and that in turn ensures that all the connected Clients keep their websockets open.

This isn't necessarily the most robust behaviour for a streaming platform to have and we will likely make it better in the future. For now though you will likely see better results by attempting to implement the code in your second example.

Hope that helped!